# How deep goes the environment variables PATH in windows?

Tags: windows, path

I've searched for this answer for a long time and can't find any occurences during my searches about this matter. How deep goes the looking for a file when windows uses the PATH env? Does it look only at depth 0 or also in subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't always choose the right keywords in our searches and after trying some links in post from stack I thought I would make a post about it:

> When a directory in %PATH% is searched for executables, are all of its
>   subdirectories searched also?

from [Windows Path Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880327/windows-path-environment-variable)

which was answered by:

> No all sub directories are not searched

and also [Add a directory and all subdirectories to the PATH variable with a single entry](https://superuser.com/questions/569466/add-a-directory-and-all-subdirectories-to-the-path-variable-with-a-single-entry)

If anyone has the reference to the microsofts docs for that, I would gladly appreciate an edit.